How can I open a Chrome profile with a proxy?
I want to use Python to open a specific chrome user profile, but it should use a proxy.
proxies = [
    "http://username:pw@ip:port",
    "http://username:pw@ip:port"
]
chrome_profiles = [
    "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 1",
    "C:/Users/Mimi/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 3"
]


profile_index = on_message.counter % len(chrome_profiles)
profile_path = chrome_profiles[profile_index]
proxy = proxies[profile_index]
on_message.counter += 1

# Open the URL in Chrome with the specified profile
url = url.replace(")","")
subprocess.Popen([
    'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
    '--user-data-dir=' + profile_path,
    '--proxy-server=' + proxy,
    url
])
print(f"Opened link: {url} with profile: {profile_path}")

That's my attempt; basically, opening the specific Chrome profile works, but the connection is dead, like no internet at all. It has to be related to how the proxy is set.
Selenium, etc. are not options for my use case. I hope someone has an idea.
Described above in detail with code snippets.

Proxies are only used for network requests. Profiles are stored in local files, it makes no sense to go through a proxy.

@Barmar i want to set proxies for them to make them as unique as possible when scraping stuff

I don't know what that means. What are you trying to make unique, and how do proxies help with that? Are you trying to hide profile information from the websites you're scraping?
